# Pulling changes from a pull request

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull-request

After I submitted a pull request. Another member of my team makes new commits to my pull request. How do I pull his changes to my original local branch?

Comment: Just pull the original branch. Pull request is just that: 'a request'. It doesn't create any other branch

Answer (score 0):

See:

- "[Pull request proficiency: Fetching abilities unlocked!](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/08/how-to-fetch-pull-requests/) "
- "[Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)"

If your other team member has pushed to the same fork as you were, a simple `git pull` (in your local PR branch) is enough.

If he/she has pushed to his/her own fork, then you would need to add the other member fork to your current  local repo remote:

```
git remote add fork2 /url/to/other/fork
```

Then fetch and merge his/her PR branch.
Since your other member will have pushed commits to

```
git fetch fork2
git merge fork2/pull/<PR#>
```